# Oracle Date Format change to yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss

Tags: java, oracle, date, timestamp

I have date saletime as 2/25/14 22:06 I want to store it in oracle table in the yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss. So I wrote following java code

```
Date saleTime = sale.getSaleTime();
            logger.info("DateTime is "+saleTime);

            SimpleDateFormat formatter=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
            Date saleTimeNorm = formatter.parse(formatter.format(saleTime));

            logger.info("DateTime after Formating "+saleTimeNorm);
            Timestamp oracleDate = new Timestamp(saleTimeNorm.getTime());

            logger.info("New Format Inserting :"+oracleDate);
                    sale.setSaleTime(oracleDate);
```

But this seems to be giving :0014-02-25 22:06:00.0

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Why would you store a date in a database as a string at all, and not as a date?

Comment: The `14` is a `yy` i.e. 2 digit year.

Comment: You probably need to change the formatter "yyyy" to "yy"

Comment: I am storing it as Date only. Setting oracleDate i.e sale.setSaleTime(oracleDate).

Comment: @Hirak saleTime already stored as Date object. I am converting it to "yyyy" format

Comment: Where is the original date coming from, and where are you seeing `0014-02-25 22:06:00.0`? You're losing the century somewhere but it isn't really clear where, without seeing what `getSaleTime()` and `setSaleTime()` are doing. I suspect you're confused about how Oracle stores dates, as they have a fixed internal representation but no intrinsic display format.

Answer (score 0):

Your `getSaleTime()` method somehow regards "14" as a four-digit year, and returns the year 14.

After you have executed `getSaleTime()`, you already have a Date variable; there is no need (and no use) in converting it to a different output format and re-parsing the result.  The Date you get from the calls to format() and parse() will be the same one you started with.

You can create your Timestamp using `getTime()` on the result of the call to `getSaleTime()`.  That will be correct once you change `getSaleTime()` so that it returns the date in the correct year.

Comment: Yes.  That is why I said it "regards '14' as a four-digit year, and returns the year 14" and "change getSaleTime() so that it returns the date in the correct year."

Answer (score 0):

Something must be wrong in your sale.getSaleTime() method. Because the following code working as needed.

```
    Date saleTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
    Date saleTimeNorm = formatter.parse(formatter.format(saleTime));
    Timestamp oracleDate = new Timestamp(saleTimeNorm.getTime());
    System.out.println(oracleDate);
//2014-05-13 03:58:53.0
```